# PHP - How to increment a filename id within braces before the dot extension?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a file that will get modify from time to time and I need to track the file name each time there are new changes to the file.
I expect to a sequence of file names eventually, for example: first-filename-1701.txt, 2nd-filename-1701(1).txt, 3rd-filename-1701(2).txt and etc..
From the results of my code below, it is producing the file names as: first-filename-1701.txt, 2nd-filename-1701(1).txt, 3rd-filename-1702(2).txt, 4th-filename-1703(3).txt and so forth.  Can someone kindly points out what I am doing wrong? Regexp is not my every day thing. Thanks.

```
$name = 'new-foo-bar-1701(1).txt';

$re1='.*?';         # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='\(([\d]+)\)'; # Round Braces 1

// set new filename
$_name = "";

// check if true
if($c=preg_match_all("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $name, $matches))
{
    $rbraces  = $matches[1][0] + 1;
    $_name .= preg_replace("/".$matches[1][0]."/", $rbraces, $name); 
}
else
{
    $_name .=$name; 
}

print $_name; // new-foo-bar-1702(2).txt
```

Comment: Well, the result for what ive tested is correct, its generating what you said. Now you want it to have 2nd, 3rd, and so forth on the filename?

Comment: Maybe http://ideone.com/CCH5B4?

Comment: its ok http://prntscr.com/axlkom

Comment: Matheus Silva - That is correct. I would like it to produce file names for 2nd, 3rd and so forth as new-foo-bar-1701(2).txt, new-foo-bar-1701(3).txt.  Only the counter in the brackets should changed by up-counting.

Comment: Well its producing... Im still confused. Its producing new-foo-bar-1701(i+1).txt for each number inside the brackets...so now you want to add 2nd-new-foo-bar-1701(2).txt ?

Comment: Please add test cases to the question.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew - Thanks.  That seem to do the trick.

Comment: @CarlBarrett: I posted the answer, please check.

Comment: posted an answer with a bit of modification required in your code

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to find matches to replace them later, that leads to over-replacement. You should replace "on the fly" using a [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) that will replace exactly what is being matched (or captured).

```
$name = 'new-foo-bar-1701(1).txt';

$re1='.*';          # Greedy match on filler
$re2='\((\d+)\)';   # Round Braces 1

// set new filename
$_name = "";

$_name .= preg_replace_callback("/(".$re1. ")".$re2."/", function($m){
    return $m[1] . "(" . ($m[2] + 1) . ")";
}, $name); 

print $_name;
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/43XC2x)

Note that since you plan to replace the numbers at the end of the string, *greedy dot matching* "filler is preferred.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - For test cases I have manually increment the file id between brackets to see each results and no changes took place on the remaining file name which works as expected. `reg_replace_callback()` surely did the job.

Comment: Glad to help, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: Do you need more help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much to change in your code except this line to

```
$_name .= preg_replace("/\(".$matches[1][0]."\)/", "(".$rbraces.")", $name);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/iuNIUo)**

**Explanation**

`\d+` is matched to `1`, but there is `1` already present twice in your string. So it is replaced to `2702(2)`.

In order to match `1` specifically from `()`, you need to put that in your regex as denoted above.